# Flexbox: space-between issue in my list

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this list `ol` with items `li` which are styled as follows:

```
ol {     
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 400px;
}

li {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fxzsx9cf/)

As you can see 3 items fit on one row. Because I'm using `justify-content: space-between` the first row looks exactly as I want it. However, the second row does not (because it has only two items). I want them to be positioned as if there was a 6th element (no gap between them and left aligned)

Is there anyway I can achieve this with flex box, or should I introduce an invisible 6th element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of achieving what you are asking by using `display:flex;` and `justify-content:space-between;`

See here more details: [W3C:Axis Alignment: the ‘justify-content’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#justify-content-property)

I would recommend using `justify-content:center;` or `justify-content:flex-start;` with margins.